# Push Notification in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement Push Notification in PCL app in Xamarin forms IOS. I have a suitable provisioning profile and p12 file that I used to send notification to native app and I'm using it on my Xamarin forms, do I need to do something more beside this changes?  I changed the AppDelegate in the IOS project to look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace Punteam.iOS
{
 [Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        String model = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model;
        String sysName = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemName;
        String sysVer = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion;
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString (model, "Model");
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString (sysName, "sysName");
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString (sysName, "sysVer");

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
        }

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    //** RegisteredForRemoteNotifications                                                           *
    //***********************************************************************************************

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // Get current device token
        var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken)) {
            DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
        }

        // Get previous device token
        var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

        // Has the token changed?
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
        {
            //TODO: Put your own logic here to notify your server that the device token has changed/been created!
        }

        // Save new device token 
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    //** ReceivedRemoteNotification                                                                 *
    //***********************************************************************************************

    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    //** ProcessNotification                                                                        *
    //***********************************************************************************************

    void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching)
    {
        // Check to see if the dictionary has the aps key.  This is the notification payload you would have sent
        if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
        {
            //Get the aps dictionary
            NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

            string alertString = string.Empty;
            string paramString = string.Empty;

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
                alertString = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("param")))
                paramString = (aps[new NSString("param")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (!fromFinishedLaunching)
            {
                //Manually show an alert
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alertString))
                {
                    UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView("Awesome Notification", alertString , null, 
                        NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Cancel", "Cancel"),
                        NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("OK", "OK"));

                    avAlert.Clicked += (sender, buttonArgs) =>
                    {
                        if (buttonArgs.ButtonIndex != avAlert.CancelButtonIndex)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramString))
                            {
//                              App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PushNotifMessageDisplay(paramString));
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    avAlert.Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    //** FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications                                                     *
    //***********************************************************************************************

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application , NSError error)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Error registering push notifications", error.LocalizedDescription, null, "OK", null).Show();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my full example for push notification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141884/2452682)

Regarding the iOS part, this is the relevant code that goes to your *AppDelegate*:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    var deviceTokenString = deviceToken.ToString().Replace("<","").Replace(">", "").Replace(" ", "");
    var notificationService = Resolver.Resolve<IPushNotificationService>();
    var pushNotificationRegister = Resolver.Resolve<IPushNotificationRegister>();

    if (pushNotificationRegister.ShouldSendToken(deviceTokenString))
    {
        var uid = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();
        notificationService.AddPushToken(deviceTokenString, DeviceUtils.GetDeviceType(), uid);
    }
}
```

***IPushNotificationRegister** - checks if the token is already sent to the server (it is done to avoid unneeded requests to the server).

***IPushNotificationService** - The service to send the token to the server.

Comment: Thanks! IdiT, you already answered, a question of main regarding Xamarin, thanks again