# Android application Services for notification

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've read that services are used to be able to run app on background. I'm planning to have a notifications using this. How should I start? I'm using Xamarin.Android

Sample codes could be helpful

Comment: it should be wcf webservice or mvc webservice or simple webservice

Comment: I'm making a mobile app.

Comment: so what, you have to use one of this as service in your async class to sendrequest for data and to receive the data

Comment: You need to register for Remote Notifications, and then I suggest you to use PushSharp to send notifications to your application. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029709/how-to-use-push-notifications-in-xamarin-forms), specially at the android part of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.com you can found anything you need to know about [backgrounding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/).
For examples you can look [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-android-apps-in-c-with-xamarin/lessons/services), tutplus is not free but they give a free trial which is enough for what you need.