# Xamarin GCM push notification not working

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

I'm following step by step, and exactly copying the code provided in the following tutorial:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/

By the way, I'm replacing with my API KEY, I'm testing using usb debug, with my moto g, running cyanogenmod, with mashmallow.

I'm not able to get the push notifications, and I don't get any errors. Any clue on this?

**UPDATE**
Here is the logcat. I have reading that sometimes this error is due a missing google-services.json, but it seeems to not be required by xamarin.

```
08-23 14:19:50.207 I/GMPM    ( 9213): App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
08-23 14:19:50.207 I/GMPM    ( 9213): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
08-23 14:19:50.216 E/GMPM    ( 9213): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
08-23 14:19:50.216 E/GMPM    ( 9213): Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
08-23 14:19:50.231 E/GMPM    ( 9213): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
08-23 14:20:26.066 I/GMPM    ( 9213): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
08-23 14:21:35.288 I/GMPM    ( 9547): App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
08-23 14:21:35.288 I/GMPM    ( 9547): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
08-23 14:21:35.295 E/GMPM    ( 9547): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
08-23 14:21:35.295 E/GMPM    ( 9547): Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
08-23 14:21:35.312 E/GMPM    ( 9547): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

[Full logcat here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7IkP5Pa6XBEaGF6MGVRdWpNNjQ/view)

Comment: There should be plenty of logs in the `adb logcat` to scour through. Which step are you failing on? It's quite a large guide in itself.

Comment: I think it's not failing. I completed the whole tutorial, I just don't get the notification without any errors in the logcat

Comment: if its debug mode, then while running the application does your OnMessage function hit? You can have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29126946/1155650.

Comment: Thank you, @JonDouglas and Rohit for the comments. I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same issue. When I initially ran the file MessageSender.exe, the message was successfully being sent to be added to my topics, but the Xamarin app did not receive any push notifications. My problem was in the WiFi router's firewall settings. As soon as I switch to my phone's 4G data network, I received the message on the device. It worked for me, but I am not sure if that's your issue. If that doesn't help, would you provide more information (logging)?