# push notification in Xamarin.forms PCL

Tags: push-notification, notifications, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to implement push notification in xamarin.forms project.

I go through these links but cannot find a good sample code.

[How to approach push notifications on Xamarin.Forms project?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20845/how-to-approach-push-notifications-on-xamarin-forms-project)

[Add push notifications to your Xamarin.Forms app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push/)

[Xamarin Push Notifications Using Azure Notifications Hub](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/761867/xamarin-push-notifications-using-azure-notifications-hub/)

[implemented Push Notifications in awesome Xamarin.Forms](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/so-i-just-implemented-push-notifications-in-awesome-xamarin-forms/)

Most of sample is using azure service. I do not use that one. The back end team will manage to send notification to device. I just need to pass token of notification and handle the given notification at my end.

I got one plugin for Push Notification but cannot find a sample or some useful code for how to use or implement it.

[xamarin-plugins for PushNotification](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029709/how-to-use-push-notifications-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I don't thinks so, because I need in Windows Phone  8.1 winrt and Windows 10. Same post is refers link which I have already mentioned in my post.
If still it is working then let me know. because I have tried it.

Comment: What is not working? can you be specific? PushSharp supports both type of windows notifications.