# How to implement Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms for IOS using PushNotification plugin

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I implemented push notifications on Xamarin Forms for the Android project following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akOREHjxGCs) video. The spoken language in the video is portuguese, but the code explains itself. The implementation is done using [this](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification) plugin. On Android, the implementation works well. I wish I could find the same implementations steps for IOS. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can always follow up with this Xamarin tutorial on the basics on how to implement push notifications on iOS:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote_notifications_in_ios/

Besides that the GitHub documentation implies this:

Call CrossPushNotification.Current from any project or PCL to gain access to APIs.

Must initialize plugin on each platform before use. If not initializated before using a method (Register/Unregister) will thow PushNotificationNotInitializedException.

CrossPushNotification.Initialize<'T'> This methods initializes push notification plugin. The generic T should be a class that implements IPushNotificationListener. This will be the class were you would listen to all push notifications events.

iOS On the AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //Consider inizializing before application initialization, if using any CrossPushNotification method during application initialization.
       CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener> ();
    //...
    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```

And I guess that you've already implement the **IPushNotificationListener**

Beside that you will need to Register/Unregister the device when needed, So I think the plugin is pretty self explained.

There is a similar thread on this topic related to this:
[How to use Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029709/how-to-use-push-notifications-in-xamarin-forms?rq=1)

Hope this helps!