# Push Notification in Xamarin forms PCL Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, chat

I have created a Xamarin Forms PCL Project.

I have a SQL Server database and when my database table is updated, I want to generate a Push Notification for my Android as well as IOS Application.

I don't want to request the table again and again. Is there any other way?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029709/how-to-use-push-notifications-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the azure but if you do not want to pay, uses Onesignal is free and works for android and ios.

For onesignal, here is a tutorial:
https://julianocustodio.com/2017/11/21/onesignal-push-notification/

Answer (score 0):

You need to write background service in android & iOS which will keep checking the table in database after fixed intervals of time and will generate notifications from it.
Also you need dependency service so that you can call platform specific services from Xamarin.Forms